# How to write that html structure in java script?

Tags: javascript

how to write that html structure in java script,

```
 <table>
<tr>
<td>
<form>
    <input  type="file"></input></td>
    <td><input type="submit"></input></td>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: append, html, innerHTML... There're plenty of ways to do the job.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumar Please check my answer. feel free to ask anything if you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following and add this before end of the `html` tag.

```
<script>
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm .setAttribute('method',"post");
myForm .setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var myInput = document.createElement("input"); 
myInput .setAttribute('type',"file");
myInput .setAttribute('name',"somename");

var formSubmit = document.createElement("input"); 
formSubmit.setAttribute('type',"submit");
formSubmit.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

myForm .appendChild(myInput);
myForm .appendChild(formSubmit);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myForm);

</script>
```

Comment: thanks it is working,but i want to add table structure in it,using javascript

Comment: @AbhishekKumar - You can define `table` in `html` `body` and then you can insert data into that table using javascipt like this.

 `var tableReference = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];`

`var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);`
This is basic sample example and you can be fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

This question does not show any research work done and also not specific question to understand.
Still if you want to display the content using javascript(render control from javascript) here is the code that will help you.

```
var strings = "<table><tr><td><form><input  type='file'></input></td><td><input type='submit'></input></td></form></table>";
document.write(strings);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume you need to append your html code to inside a div called `#my_div_id` then use following code. (I have used your html code inside my method)

You should import jQuery library to this solution work.

```
function appendMyCode(){
    $("#my_div_id").html("\
    <table>\
    <tr>\
    <td>\
    <form>\
        <input  type=\"file\"></input></td>\
        <td><input type=\"submit\"></input></td>\
    </form>\
    </table>\
    ");
}
```

output will be, html table you used will append to `my_div_id` div.
I have used `"\"` character for detect line endings inside a string.
because your html code should pass to `.html()` method as a string

Comment: no your code is in jquery  i just want that code in javascript.